How to check if regedit is available to run
I'm working on a process that creates an EC2 instance running Windows Server 2022 Datacenter, installs software and then tries to add registry entries in order to set some default preferences for the software. It adds registry entries by writing a .reg file and executing it with regedit using an SSM command.
If I run this process after the start up, everything runs as expected. If I run it as part of the start up process, the .reg file gets generated and written, but the registries aren't added.
Written test registries for software that doesn't exist.  I tried this in case the registries I was writing got overridden later.  They again were written after start up, but not during the start up process.
I suspect that the regedit command is unavailable when I'm calling it.  Is there a way to check and wait for it's availability?
